# Why address bus bit and data bus bit different

Tags: memory, rom

Recently I read address bus is 16 and 4 bit data/address in ROM.

Comment: Why do you need a 16-bit wide data bus?

Comment: They don't convey the same information. So if the type of information differ, why should they be similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data bus width determines how many bits can be simultaneously read from or written to memory or other devices on the bus. 4-bit data bus is very unusual these days. 8-bit, 16-bit and 32-bit are more common.

The address bus width determines how many unique addresses can be managed. The number is 2<sup>n</sup> where *n* is the number of address lines. With 16 lines this is 2<sup>16</sup> = 65536 unique addresses.

Comment: I have encountered a 4-bit data bus on a 2-line LCD - it could either be connected via eight pins (one GPIO port) or sixteen. In four-bit data mode, data would get transmitted over two cycles plus one for the opcode. The remaining pins were data transfer control.

Comment: I'd forgotten the 4-bit LCD bus which is used on all the Hitachi LCDs common with the Arduino boards, etc. I've used these but all the complexity of sending 8-bit bytes is handled by the library. Maybe that's why I forgot!

Comment: The LCD I had to deal with was very similar to those, but the controller was quite a bit smarter than this one. I also had no access to a library, just the opcode sheet.